# Does hangfire work to avoid always on of Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, hangfire

Let met try to explain. I have added an application on Azure but as i have the basic plan it is not able for me the ALWAYS ON and sometimes my application goes idle and a friend told me i could try implementing a recurring job using hangfire to every minute make something to avoid that. I think the method is being called according azure log stream but the application is being idle anyway.

Could anyone try to explain me that and give me one tip? It is not possible for me change my plan right now cause the price is 10x what i am currently paying.

My recurring job is coded like that

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ICampanhaRepository>(x => x.GetAllAsync(), Cron.Minutely);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your Web App Active, You can create a custom class inside your .Net App that pings your Web URL:-

I have added one **PingController.cs**:-

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Ping()
    {
        return Ok("Ping received");
    }
}
```

I have added one **PingService.cs**:-

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class PingService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _pingEndpoint;
    private Timer _timer;

    public PingService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _pingEndpoint = "https://webappping.azurewebsites.net/"; // Replace with your endpoint
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(PerformPing, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)); // Change the interval as needed

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async void PerformPing(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_pingEndpoint);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle any exceptions or log them
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Updated Program.cs to call this ping service:-

**Program.cs:-**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<PingService>(); // Add HTTP client for PingService
builder.Services.AddHostedService<PingService>(); // Register PingService as a hosted service
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**Output:-**

[image]

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789895/how-to-prevent-an-azure-website-from-going-to-sleep) by **cyberspy**, You can make use of [uptimerobot](https://uptimerobot.com/) to monitor your web app and ping it for Free every 1 minute, This will also help keep your Web app active without the need of Always ON feature.

[image]

[image]

And then Create Monitor to start your Web App monitoring.